# How to fix the broken images even though I create the code that retrieves all images from the folder

Tags: php, image

I've got the broken images when I try to retrieve all jpg files from the folder where the name is 'imgProduct'.

The error message is 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'

The directory of all images is C:\Sungsan\imgProduct.

And the directory of code below is C:\Sungsan\Website\view\shopPanel.php.

```
<?php
$productImg = glob("../imgProduct/*.jpg*");
echo var_dump($productImg).'<br>';

for($a = 0; $a < count($productImg); $a++) {
 $num = $productImg[$a];
 echo basename($num)."<br />";
 echo '<img src="' .$num. '" alt="random image"> <br />';
}
?>
```

[This image is the result that code above is excuted.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu4DP.png)

I was searching for how to troubleshoot this broken images but I have no idea. Hope to give recommendation or suggestion. Thanks

Comment: What are the file names of the images that don't work?

Comment: Remove basename()

Comment: Are you sure something like `../imgProduct/img01.jpg` is correct inside `src=""`? On the other hand, if you wanted to save your result from `basename()` you should have done so.

Answer (score 0):

Your `basepath` makes `../imgProduct/img01.jpg` to be `img01.jpg`. And I assume that your web root is not inside `imgProduct`, so you need to append it:

```
$num = basename($num);
echo "{$num}<br/><img src='/imgProduct/{$num}' alt='random image'> <br />";
```

Also don't mistaken server-side path with web-side url. `../imgPorduct/img01.jpg` is going back in your URL from current website page, not from PHP file

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong, but by the looks of it you're trying to reference files in the wrong directory?
Change your image src to point to the folder containing the images (currently it's seemingly looking for 'img1.jpg' in the web pages current directory.

```
echo '<img src="../imgProduct/' .$num. '" alt="random image"> <br />';
```

After looking at your screenshot again and reading some of the comments, I've also noticed that you could likely also just remove basename as it is stripping out the rest of the file path.

Hope this helps.